# Is it possible to install openssl in openshift?

Tags: docker, openssl, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

I have a script that encrypts the files that are created by my application. The script is a bat file, I am changing it to shell script because in openshift we use wildfly server in centOS and the script uses OpenSSL.

My question is

1. Is it possible to install OpenSSL in the container or image. If so, is there any issue?
2. Or do we need to create custom openshift container which has openssl installed.

I am new to openshift and all. So not aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes" - practically, you can add to a container image any tool that you need. It is usually regarded as a good practice to add *only* what you need to keep the image size small.

It is quite possible that there's an image already "out there" that has `openssl` installed on `centos`. You may have to build the image for reasons like security, company policies, etc.

First, create a new image from a base image. A sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:centos7

# Switch to root to be able to install stuff
USER 0

# -y for unattended install
RUN yum install -y curl \
 # clean up the yum cache
 && yum clean all
```

[Build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) the image, then [push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) it to a Docker registry. Next, reference the image in the [deployment](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/deployments/how_deployments_work.html#creating-a-deployment-configuration) configuration as the image for a container.

With OpenShift you actually have the option of [building](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html) images on OpenShift, including using [Docker builds](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#docker-strategy-options), and saving them automatically in OpenShift's integrated Docker registry.